# Laravel model is updating multiple models instead of single

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to update my model using multiple where conditions.

my code is

```
public function UpdateEducationData(Request $request)
    {
        $user = app('user');
        //        return $request;
        $education = eduinfo::where("id", $user->id)->where("exam", $request->type)->first();
        // dump sql query for debugging
        //        $education->rawSql();
        //        dd($education);
        $education->board = $request->board;
        // $education->degree = $request->degree;
        $education->year = $request->year;
        $education->rollno = $request->rollno;
        $education->obtainmarks = $request->obtainmarks;
        $education->totalmarks = $request->totalmarks;
        $education->division = $request->division;
        $education->grade = $request->grade;
        $education->totalcgpa = $request->totalcgpa;
        $education->obtailcgpa = $request->obtailcgpa;
        // update education based on exam
        $education->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Education Information Updated Successfully");
        return "Update Education Data";
    }
```

My code is updating a eduinfo table based on id and exam. But whenever this function is called it updates all eduinfo records related to that user id.

I tried to update eduinfo table single record but multiple records are being update at once. I dumped eduinfo after retriving the model and yes it's retrieving the single model using first() method but still when save() is called it updates all records of that user id in eduinfo.

Comment: are there multiple records with the same 'id'?

Comment: @lagbox Even if there are, he is calling `first` so it can not update multiple records at once.

Comment: Can u use `dump` method to debug tour education model, just to make sure you are calling `UpdateEducationData` method once

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli yes multiple records could be updated ... the generated update statement is only restricted by the 'id' field (which multiple records could share in this scenario)

Comment: @lagbox He is calling `first` method of eloquent. Even if there are multiple records with `$user->id` it doesn't matter. Eloquent will order it by `id` and limit it by 1 to return only first one record. So there is no possibility to update multiple records after calling first

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli the generated SQL for the UPDATE statement is only restricted by the primary key so if multiple records have that same key they would also be updated ...

Comment: @lagbox So you mean eloquent return single records but generated query acts "wrong" for his case. Yes, that make sense. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: As @lagbox said you definitely have more than 1 record with the same `id`. `id` is your primary key so it should be `unique` in database. Make sure to give it `primary` index and `autoincrement` behaviour in mysql.

Comment: Are you sure about your condition to make unique record?

Comment: @lagbox exactly there are multiple records using same id

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli yes i am making that sure i have debugged that as well it's giving me one model as i desire and yes I am calling this method once.

Comment: @lagbox currently I can't make id unique for eduinfo but is there any possiblty to use multiple where condition to update record

Comment: @lagbox Is there any way that i can use multiple keys while updating ?

Comment: Eloquent does not support composite keys by default but there may be a package out there that gives you that ability